# How can I keep the mask of a UITextView in sync with its frame

Tags: ios, swift

Here is a GIF illustrating the problem:

[image]

Here is the code I have currently, It simply rounds the top two corners of the UITextView.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, self.view.frame.width - 40, 60))
textView.bounces = false
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: textView.bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: (UIRectCorner.TopLeft | UIRectCorner.TopRight),
            cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(8, 8)
        )
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = textView.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
        textView.layer.mask = maskLayer

        self.view.addSubview(textView)
    }

}
```

I tried subclassing `UITextView` and overriding `layoutSubviews` like this:

```
class TextView: UITextView {
    var maskLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

But that ends up with a strange animation:

[image]

My question is: How do I keep the two in sync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution in `layoutSubviews` is right. The problem is that changes to Core Animation layers are implicitly animated. You can prevent this by wrapping the frame change in a `CATransaction`, and setting a property of that transaction that disables Core Animation actions:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    maskLayer.frame = bounds
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: Champion! Thanks Stuart.